# \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Uniqueness with namespaces

Tags: phalcon

I am get the following Phalcon\Db\Exception below when using \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Uniqueness validator with a model that is a namespace. Looks like validator class is not using getSource method from the Model when building the supporting query.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near app\dao\users  WHERE username = 'nhidalgo' AND id <> ''' at line
>   1 when executing SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM app\dao\users  WHERE
>   username = 'nhidalgo' AND id <> ''

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
namespace App\Dao;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Inclusionin;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Uniqueness;

class Users extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSource('users');
    }

    public function validation()
    {
        $this->validate(new Uniqueness(
            array(
                "field"   => "username",
                "message" => "Username must be unique"
            )
        ));
        $this->validate(new Uniqueness(
            array(
                "field"   => "email",
                "message" => "Email must be unique"
            )
        ));

        return !$this->validationHasFailed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that if you use namespaces you MUST implement the method that returns the table name.

```
public function getSource()
{
    return 'users';
}
```

[setSource](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/0.5.0/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model.html) only changes the mapped table for a single instance, while implementing [getSource](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/0.5.0/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model.html) makes the source available for every instance created.